# Optimization with/without an analytical gradient

Tags: optimization, numerics

A colleague is optimizing a function (e.g. trying to find the minimum of a function $f(x_1, x_2, \ldots)$). We know the analytical form and it is differentiable. I suggested calculating the derivatives of the function and supplying those to the optimizer. Another colleague said that this is a bad approach and it's always better to let optimizers approximate the gradient numerically.

I didn't understand this remark. Is it true? If so, why?

Comment: As in many cases where a simple bold generalization is made, the reality is far more subtle.  A good introduction to some of the issues (both for and against your colleague's assertion) can be found in the chapter on optimization in the *Numerical Recipes* books.

Comment: I'd say that in the vast majority of situations that come up in statistics and machine learning, it's *very much preferable* to use (analytically or automatically) computed gradients rather than numerical ones. As long as they can be computed reasonably efficiently – and the implementation is correct – you'll typically get (essentially) the same value out of computing the gradient either way, but with orders of magnitude less computation with the analytical/autodiff approach. (There are of course [exceptions](https://blog.openai.com/nonlinear-computation-in-linear-networks/).)